# Explicit homotopy on showing that $\pi_n(X,x_0)$ is abelian for $n \geq 2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to show that $\pi_n(X,x_0)$ is abelian for $n \geq 2$. Given two maps $f,g:(I^n,\partial I^n)\to(X,x_0)$, I want to construct an explicit homotopy rel $\partial I^n$ from $f + g$ to $g + f$. I saw the following picture below, in Hatcher, but how can I write down this homotopy in formulas?
[image]

Comment: There's a good reason it's not written out in Hatcher—the picture says so much more than the formulas could.  But if you must, start by writing down homotopies between the rectangles for $f$ and $g$ at each step.

Comment: I would expect that you want to show that $f*g$ is homotopic to $g*f$. I have my doubts whether you can show that there is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$ for arbitrary $f, g$. (But I'd appreciate to get to see one).

Comment: You are taking too restrictive a view of the possibilities of language and symbols. Have a look at the proofs in Section 6,4 of "Nonabelian Algebraic Topology" available from groupoids.org.uk. Read the book "Flatland". Think about "higher dimensional algebra", .

Comment: @Thomas If $f$ were homotopic to $g$ for arbitary $f$ and $g$, that would imply $\pi_n(X,x_0) = 0$ for all $X$ and $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes, obviously. But if you take the time for reading the question, you will find that the OP is asking exactly for this. My point is that the question should be about a homotopy from $f*g$ to $g*f$ instead of one from $f$ to $g$.

Comment: What I would do is write down the Eckmann-Hilton argument. In this situation, most of the $=$'s in it are actual $=$'s; and the ones that aren't have pretty straightforward homotopies underlying them. So if you just go through EH you should get an explicit homotopy out of it.

Comment: @Thomas Now I understand your original comment.  I assumed he was writing about a homotopy from $f*g$ to $g*f$ based on the image he included.  But he had in fact written “from $f$ to $g$” in [his (pre-edited) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3499261/revisions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not difficult. For the sake of "symmetric" formulas let us replace $I^n$ by $J^n$, where $J = [-1,1]$. Then
$$(f + g)(s_1,\ldots,s_n) = \begin{cases} f(2s_1+1,s_2,\ldots,s_n) & s_1 \le 0 \\ g(2s_1-1,s_2,\ldots,s_n) & s_1 \ge 0 \end{cases} $$

Write $J^n = J^2 \times J^{n-2} $. Define a homeomorphism $h : J^2 \to D^2$ by linearly compressing the line segment between $z \in \partial J^2$ and $0$ to the line segment between $\frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}$ and $0$. Let $G : D^2 \times I \to D^2$ denote the homotopy $G(z,t) = e^{t\pi i} z$, which rotates the disk $D^2$ by an angle of $\pi$. We have $G_1(z) = -z$. Define $H = h^{-1} \circ G \circ (h \times id_I)$ and $R = H_1 \times id_{J^{n-2}}$. This is a homeomorphism homotopic to $id_{J^n}$ via a homotopy of pairs on $(J^n,\partial J^n)$. We have $R(s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n)  = (-s_1,-s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n)$.

Then $\phi : (J^n,\partial J^n) \to (X,x_0)$ and $\phi \circ R$ represent the same element in $\pi_n(X,x_0)$. But now we get
$$(f + g) \circ R = g \circ R + f \circ R .$$
To see this, let $s_1 \le 0$. Then
$$(g \circ R + f \circ R)(s_1,\ldots,s_n)) = (g \circ R)(2s_1+1,\ldots,s_n) = g(-2s_1-1,-s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n)$$
and because $-s_1  \ge 0$
$$(f + g)(R(s_1,\ldots,s_n)) = (f+g)(-s_1,-s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n) = g(2(-s_1)-1,-s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n) = (g \circ R + f \circ R)(s_1,\ldots,s_n) .$$
The case $s_1 \ge 0$ is treated similarly.

We conclude
$$[f  + g] = [(f + g)\circ R] = [g \circ R + f \circ R] = [ g + f].$$

Remark: Hatcher's homotopy is more complicated because he first "compresses" the $f,g$-parts into the interior of $I^n$ and then makes a deformation of $I^n$ *not rotating* the smaller $f,g$-parts. Explicitly describing this deformation is probably not easy.